# Dedicated server configuration - some tips -Xenserver/Debian

Tags: debian, ruby, xenserver, drupal, dedicated-server

I am migrating from a vps based hosting to a dedicated hosting (8GB RAM/1TB HD). I need to run multiple Drupal and Ruby based applications? what would be the recommended configuration. I was thinking of two options.

1) Install multiple Debian os on top of Xen (like VPS). Each may be 2GB Memory and run Drupal and Ruby and MYSQL on separate partitions .

2) Install one instance of Debian. and Install Drupal (Apache, php) Ruby (lighttpd, ruby) ,MySQL all in the same partition

I was little worried that option 2 could lead to some performance issues later..

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your first option.

XenServer (Free/Community edition) will let you run your VM instances with minimal overhead (like VPS). With the extra features of cloning (setup one VM, clone it as you wish) and taking snapshots at anytime with no downtime. That will make your work so much easier.

Comment: My background is more of programming , but successfully configured Debian .
On top of your head, does XENServer provide any graphical interface to partition and install multiple Debian, or pretty much i have to do everything manually

Comment: XenServer will let you provisioning your VMs with an already installed Debian image. All you'll need to set for your guests is virtual memory, disk size and root password. You'll also have a GUI access (VNC) by default.